# Casting to a jar class

Tags: java, interface, casting, executable-jar, instanceof

I have a jar file, CallMe.jar, containing a mainClass CallMe.class which implements an interface CallInterface.class.

From anoher application I access CallMe.jar , then I create an instance of CallMe.class ( I used special classes designed to load classes from a jar file, that you can find there : http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077572/learn-java/java-tip-70--create-objects-from-jar-files-.html ).

Here is my code:

```
String jarPath = "/path/to/CallMe.jar";
String mainClass = "callme.CallMe";
JarClassLoader jarLoader = new JarClassLoader(jarPath); // Loads the jar
Class c = jarLoader.loadClass(mainClass, true); // Loads the specified class inside the jar.
Object jarObject = c.newInstance(); // Creates an instance of this mainClass CallMe
```

Since the mainClass CallMe.class implements CallInterface.class and overrides the method interfaceMethod(), I want to call this method by casting CallInterface to my object. But for that it seems I need this class to be imported in my current application.

Let's consider the CallInterface could be located in any package of my jar :
 CallMe.jar -> any.package.CallInterface.class
            -> callme.CallMe.class

In my current application project I have the CallInterface in a different package : appli.jarLoader.CallInterface.class

If I assume that the two CallInterface.class classes are the same (but probably in different package), how can I reference (casting) the one that is in the jar?

My current testing code is the following :

```
if( jarObject instanceof appli.jarLoader.CallInterface) { // The CallInterface in my application
    Print.str(DEBUGGING, "jarObject is instance!");
  appli.jarLoader.CallInterface ci = (appli.jarLoader.CallInterface) jarObject;
  ci.interfaceMethod();
}
else {
  Print.str(DEBUGGING, "jarObject not instance...");
}
```

The condition if not verified. When I try this :

```
Object appliObject = new Appli(); // implements appli.jarLoader.CallInterface 

if(appliObject instanceof appli.jarLoader.CallInterface) {
    Print.str(DEBUGGING, "appliObject is instance!");
  appli.jarLoader.CallInterface ci = (appli.jarLoader.CallInterface) appliObject;
  ci.interfaceMethod();
}
else {
    Print.str(DEBUGGING, "appliObject is not instance...");
}
```

In this case the condition is verified and I can access the overidden interface method.

How can I access the interface method in my implementing class in the jar file? How can I succeed in casting my jarObject with ClassInterface ?

---

EDIT 1

The idea is that my applications know only of the ClassInterface and nothing about the implementing classes, which means I cannot just hardcode imlementing class

Comment: "If I assume that the two CallInterface.class classes are the same (but probably in different package), how can I reference (casting) the one that is in the jar" - By importing the class that it is in the jar?

Comment: I would like to load the classes at running time, I don't know if its possible to import at run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your loaded `jarObject` implements `any.package.CallInterface`, I assume casting this object to `appli.jarLoader.CallInterface` will result in a runtime casting exception.

If you want to cast the object to the interface packaged in the jar, you will have to add it also to your project.

If you are sure about the signature (name + argumentlist) of the method you want to call you can use reflection to call your method:

```
Method m=jarObject.getClass().getMethod("methodName",Class<?>...);
m.invoke(jarObject, ...);
```